Value of index randomly changes in dynamic character array during for loop
For one of my assignments in my C book, I have to find a way to treat characters as integers. So, I wrote a program that takes an array of characters that represent integers, add them up, and output the result. In the following program, I attempt to ‘add’ the strings ‘123’ and ‘321’ which should result in ‘444’.
To do this, I first find the distance from ‘3’, ‘2’, and ‘1’ from ‘0’, respectively. For example, ’3’ is 51 in ASCII and ‘0’ 48, so the difference (or distance) is the 3 ASCII code which translates to ETX. Refer to the table below.
ASCII table
The following is the implementation. Print statements are included for debugging purposes:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char *num1 = "123";
        char *num2 = "321";
        const char Z = 48; //value of zero 
        char from_z = 0;
        char total[] = { 0 };
        int i = 0;
        
        //main for loop
        for (i = 0; num1[i] != '\0' || num2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                from_z = num2[i] - Z; //distance from '0'
                total[i] = num1[i] + from_z;

                //print out contents of current index and previous
                //to compare
                printf("i total[%d]: %c\n", i, total[i]);
                printf("i - 1: total[%d]: %c\n", i-1, total[i-1]);
        } 
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        total[i] = '\0';
        
        return 0;
}

The Bug:
When I assign and print the newly assigned index and the previously assigned one, during the second iteration, the value of total[1] changes from ‘4’ to ‘\x01’. Yet, total[0] and total[2] still contain ‘4’. Check the output below. (Of course '\x01' would print out nothing)
i total[0]: 4
i - 1: total[-1]:
i total[1]: 4
i - 1: total[0]: 4
i total[2]: 4
i - 1: total[1]:
i: 3

As you can see, total[1] was first ‘4', and then randomly became blank. Using the debugger, I could tell that the contents of total[1] is \x01.
What fixed it:
Having a static array where I defined total to have 4 indices like so: char total[4] = { 0 };, the problem was fixed. But I’d still like to know why it doesn’t work for dynamic arrays.

The array total is defined as having a size of 1. You try to write more than one character to it. This is undefined behavior. I suspect you expect that array to dynamically grow. C does not have such a feature.

Use const int Z = '0'; if you want to name it, but you could simply write '0' where you use Z.

char total[] = { 0 };

is not a dynamic array -- it is a fixed-size array with a single element.  Writing to any element other than total[0] is writing outside the bounds of the array and invokes undefined behavior.
C doesn't have "dynamic" arrays that automatically grow as you write new elements to them.  If you need a resizable array, you need to allocate memory with either malloc or calloc:
#include <stdlib.h>
...
size_t totalSize = 1;
char *total = calloc( totalSize, sizeof *total ); 

and then manually resize it as necessary using realloc:
if ( i == totalSize )
{
  char *tmp = realloc( total, sizeof *total * (totalSize * 2) );
  if ( tmp )
  {
    total = tmp;
    totalSize *= 2;
  }
}

Make sure to clean up after yourself when you're done:
free( total );


Can't upvote because not enough rep, but thanks!

@AsianDora: You're welcome.  A couple of other notes -- use the character literal '0' instead of 48; all the world is not ASCII.  And you don't need the variable Z at all, just use the literal.  Also, don't use dynamic memory if you don't need to -- if you can get away with defining a fixed-size array large enough for your needs, do that instead.  Managing memory is a pain in the ass in C.


Having a static array where I defined total to have 4 indices like so: char total[4] = { 0 };, the problem was fixed. But I’d still like to know why it doesn’t work for dynamic arrays.

There is nothing in your code that could reasonably be called a "dynamic array".  In particular, this ...

char total[] = { 0 };


... declares a 1-element array, and that array contains exactly one element for its entire lifetime. If you attempt to access elements of that array at index 1 or greater then you obtain undefined behavior, which is apparently what you in fact observed.
If you can determine in advance a reasonable upper bound on the size you need, then declaring an array of (explicitly) that maximal size is a pretty good way to go.  This is the solution you describe.  If you don't want to decide until runtime how many elements to reserve then dynamic memory allocation via malloc() or calloc() is probably needed.  Note well that even with dynamic allocation, the size of the allocated object is still constant throughout its lifetime.
